# Changing Power Scheme settings through Registry instead of Control Panel in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, control-panel

I'd like to change the settings of a power scheme (say, go to sleep after 45 minutes instead of 30) through the registry, rather than the control panel, in Windows 7. I'd also like to turn hot keys off the same way.

Any suggestions how I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could learn to manipulate it through WMI classes & some powershell.  More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802301/programmatically-change-windows-power-settings

Answer (score 0):

Provided there are no direct documentations that describes those keys, you could take a snapshot of your registry before you make a change and right after and compare the differences to try to find which specific key relates to these settings. You can use a tool such as [CRegistry Comparison](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cregistry/).

Comment: I've tried comparing before and after, but it wasn't enlightening as I hoped it would. Seemed almost like random entries...